# Convert multiple numbers or text from a column into a row without duplicates

Tags: excel, duplicates

[image]

See the image. I want the column to be converted into the row as in the image. Even if there are multiple text or numbers with commas in any single row within the column, then those needs to be considered as duplicates. How do I make the row that I have using a formula?

Comment: Are you looking for a VBA or formula solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try this small user defined function:

```
Public Function MakeList(rng As Range) As String
    Dim c As Collection, r As Range, s As String
    Set c = New Collection
    For Each r In rng
        ary = Split(r.Value, ",")
        For Each a In ary
            On Error Resume Next
                c.Add a, CStr(a)
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                MakeList = MakeList & "," & a
            Else
                Err.Number = 0
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next a
    Next r
    MakeList = Mid(MakeList, 2)
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: Where do I put the VBA code? I have no idea how to do this. I was actually looking for a built-in formula within excel

Comment: PressAlt+11, then insert a module and paste the code into the module.